# How do you detect collisions between two arrays?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

For future refrence  this was the final code

```
for each (var bullet:Bullet in bulletList)
{
    for each (var zombie:Zombie in zombieList)
    {
        if (zombie.hitTestObject(bullet))
        {
            stage.removeChild(bullet);
            zombie.zombieShot(50);
        }

    }
}
```

### Original Question Below

```
 for each (var bullet:Bullet in bulletList)
{
    if (zombieList.length > 0)
    {
        if (zombieList[h].hitTestObject(bullet))
        {
            bulletList[i].deleteBullet();
            zombieList[h].zombieShot(50);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I have but it only detects the first zombie I spawn in, any help is appreciated.

```
if (countMePls<10)
{
    countMePls++;
    var zombie:Zombie = new Zombie(stage,Math.random() * stage.width,Math.random()*stage.height);
    zombie.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE,zombieRemoved,false,0,true);
    zombieList.push(zombie);
    stage.addChild(zombie);
}
```

and then...

```
function shootBullet():void
{
var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(stage,Main.player.x,Main.player.y,Main.player.rotation - 90);
bullet.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE,bulletRemoved,false,0,true);
bulletList.push(bullet);
stage.addChildAt(bullet,1);
}
```

this last bit is in Bullet.as

```
public function deleteBullet():void
    {
        this.parent.removeChild(this)
    }
```

Comment: And does your code compile? (of course using c# compiler since you tagged your question so)

Comment: Yes but only the first zombie dies then the second, not in a random order.

Comment: `it only detects the first zombie I spawn in`, so where is that code?

Comment: Where are `i` and `h` coming from? Those variables are declared or assigned to in the code you posted so I don't see how you would expect it to access other objects.

Comment: I can add full code, and I compile in the flash ide

Comment: @user3096960 then why have you tagged `c#` ?

Comment: I thought the difference between c# and as3 was basically none so I did, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue comes from some basic confusion about `for` and `for each`. With for each you have no index variable, each iteration yields a new instance of the type in the collection which is referred to by the name you declare in the loop. In this case that is;

```
  foreach (var bullet in bulletsList)
  {
      // do something with bullet
  }
```

You probably actually want a nested loop, something that checks every bullet against each zombie to see if there was a hit, that would actually look like this;

```
  foreach (var bullt in bulletsList)
  {
       foreach (var zombie in zombiesList)
       {
             if (zombie.hitTestObject(bullet))
             {
                     bulletList.Remove(bullet);
                     zombie.zombieShot(50);
             }
       }
  }
```

In your code you have the foreach loop giving you the current `bullet` object but then you never reference it within the loop, that doesn't make sense. This may not be exactly what you want but hopefully it will get you moving in the right direction. If you want to use those indexers then you need something like;

```
  for (int i = 0; i < bulletsList.Length; i++)
  {
       for (int h = 0; h < zombiesList.Length; h++)
       {
            // do stuff with bulletsList[i] and zombiesList[h]
       }
  }
```

Note: this was originally tagged as C# and the code I've posted uses C# syntax. The explanation I've provided most likely applies either way, the OP's code doesn't really makes sense in any language I know of and the reasons are the same.

Comment: This gives me a type error saying deleteBullet doesn't exist, how do I tell it which bullet to remove if I just do this this.parent.removeChild(bullet)

Comment: @user3096960 I removed that code from my samples. However, in your original code you have `bulletList[i].deleteBullet();` which is calling `deleteBullet()` on the bullet instance at index `i` so you should get that same error regardless of whether you're using a for or foreach loop. In both cases you're trying to call that method on a bullet instance, the bullet class doesn't contain that method then you will get an error like that.

Comment: With a couple of modifications I made the second one work, thanks!